# How to decode a viewstate containing %2F and %2B in between

Tags: asp.net, security, viewstate

i am trying to decode a viewstate value that contains %2F and %2B in between. Help me to find a way to decode this format of viewstate. If You need value please reply...

I tried converting %2F and %2B to / and +, respectively. But it doesn't seem to get decoded through the decoders.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.